# A Polish manual of style.

Tags: resources, style

English language has a number of popular manuals of style. There's Chicago Manual of Style, Elements of Style etc.

Do you know any such resource for the Polish language?

Comment: Strunk & White isn't a manual of style.

Comment: Assuming he means [The Elements of Style](http://www.bartleby.com/141/), the word "style" ought to defend his statement. @Tadeusz - you might have to consult a Polish-language resource (website).

Comment: @Ralph Grammar certainly does change.  Somewhat glacially, mayhap, but it can and does.  Just had to be said.

Comment: @QuickerSnarkerBacker: I like Tadeusz's question, because it's a nice test (if you will) for writers.SE being non-English-only (or is it?  Thought it wasn't (supposed to be))

Comment: @Ralph - *The Elements of Style* is explicitly not a grammar guide, even though it does touch on grammar. For more information on this, have a look at [this thread in EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2909/161). However, it isn't a manual of style in the same vein as Chicago or AP; *Elements  of Style* is more of a polemic on the virtues of a particular style.

Comment: Have started a bounty on this, how could an entire language doesn't not have any style resources at all? If there are several, scattered style guides for specific uses, as [this answer](http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/1245/26) suggests, we could at least summarize those.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that there is a generic manual of style for the Polish language. Different universities and government bodies may publish style manuals for specific publications (such as official government documents, or paper submission), but nothing general.

It's also worth noting that there are several dialects of Polish in use, which may influence the writing style of the author in ways that won't be compatible with a common style-document

Answer (score 3):

After a considerable bit of research, I came across this on the Polish language Wikipedia page on proofreading ([Korekta tekstu](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korekta_tekstu)).

From the Google-provided broken English translation:

> ### [Style guides](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korekta_tekstu#Poradniki_stylistyczne)
>
> These guides are usually created by employees internally or supplied by the customer and should distinguish them from professional sources for formatting and style of the language of documents, such as "The Chicago Manual of Style" (CMS), "The Associated Press Stylebook and Briefing on Media Law "(AP Stylebook)," The Elements of Style "and" The Gregg Reference Manual: A Manual of Style, Grammar, Usage, and Formatting. " **(Polish publications include handbooks normative culture of the Polish language, eg by H. Jadackiej, A. Markowski, correct Polish PWN dictionaries, and other, one must add that they relate primarily linguistic layers, whereas those English-language sources also include a recommendation for formatting etc. - editor. crowd.)** In the case of a conflict, proofreaders mark the errors as the internal reference guide instead of the material.

And in the original Polish:

> ### [Poradniki stylistyczne](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korekta_tekstu#Poradniki_stylistyczne)
>
> Takie poradniki są zwykle tworzone wewnętrznie przez pracowników lub dostarczane przez klienta i należy odróżniać je od profesjonalnych źródeł dotyczących formatowania i stylu językowego dokumentów, jak np. "The Chicago Manual of Style" (CMS), "The Associated Press Stylebook and Briefing on Media Law", (AP Stylebook), "The Elements of Style" czy"The Gregg Reference Manual: A Manual of Style, Grammar, Usage, and Formatting". **(polskie wydawnictwa normatywne to m.in. podręczniki kultury języka polskiego, m.in. autorstwa H. Jadackiej, A. Markowskiego, słowniki poprawnej polszczyzny PWN i inne, trzeba jednak dodać, że dotyczą one przede wszystkim warstwy językowej, natomiast wymienione źródła anglojęzyczne zawierają także zalecenie dotyczące formatowanie etc. – przyp. tłum.)** W razie kolizji norm, korektorzy zaznaczają błędy zgodnie z wewnętrznym poradnikiem zamiast z materiałem.

So the closest thing to an accepted and universal "manual of style" in the Polish language (according to Wikipedia) is the *[Książka Kultura języka polskiego](http://ksiegarnia.pwn.pl/produkt/7112/kultura-jezyka-polskiego-t-3.html)* (*The book of Polish Language and Culture*) by Hanna Jadacka (*T.1.: Inflection, word formation, syntax*), Andrzej Markowski (*T.2.: Theory, Lexical Issues*), and Thomas Karpowicz (*T.3.: Pronunciation, spelling, punctuation*). And if there are issues of preferred writing style, each publication uses its own internal reference guides.

### Other Style Guides for the Polish Language

In addition to *The book of Polish Language and Culture* (which appears to be a general reference of grammar, syntax and punctuation), there are other international style guides which are provide rules for the proper translation of laws, regulations and business practices into several languages, including Polish.

One is the European Union's Interinstitutional Style Guide ([EN](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-000100.htm), [PL](http://publications.europa.eu/code/pl/pl-000100.htm)), which provides detailed information on the proper use of several linguistic concepts in all 23 languages of the EU.

Another is the [International Standards Organization](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html) (ISO) which provides several international standards for businesses and government. There are many, many different documents on the proper use of style in several international languages (including Polish) that are dependent on the situation (such as ISO 31 for quantities and units or ISO 5966 for the presentation of scientific and technical reports).

Tangentially related, the European Committee for Standardization (CEN) also provides a  certification called EN-15038 which is an international standard for translation service providers that ensures proper translation into various languages. The *PKN EN 15038* is the version specifically for the Polish Language. You have to pay CEN to find out exactly what is entailed with being EN-15038 certified in Polish, but you can get some idea [here](http://qualitystandard.bs.en-15038.com/).